# Как объявить зависимость для всех artefactId?

Tags: gradle

Можно ли в Gradle как-то написать зависимость для всех artefactId?

```
compile 'com.android.support:*:27.1.1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, так сделать нельзя. И, на самом деле, вам это не нужно. Предположим, так сделать можно, и вы в зависимостях требуете все артифакты из группы. Что может пойти не так? Автор выпустит ещё одну библиотеку в этой группе. И тогда:

1. Вы подтянете новую библиотеку в зависимости, даже если она вам не нужна, и она будет мёртвым грузом лежать в вашем приложении.
2. В новой библиотеке может оказаться класс, ломающий вашу логику, и вы об этом узнаете только в рантайме (особенно актуально, если пользоваться чем-нибудь вроде Spring'а, который сканирует весь classpath в поисках бинов).
3. В новой библиотеке может оказаться версия класса, конфликтующая с версией класса, подгруженной из другой библиотеки. Об этом вы, в худшем случае, тоже узнаете только в рантайме.

Вследствие всего этого билд перестанет быть предсказуемым - собрав приложение из одного и того же кода в разные моменты времени, вы получите разные версии приложения. Поэтому такую фичу и не добавляют в Gradle - это не только бесполезно, но и опасно.

Десять раз подумайте, зачем вам подключать *все* библиотеки из группы. По данным [MVNrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=com.android.support) их там 91 штука, некоторые дублируют друг друга (например, `preference-v7` и `preference-v14`), обеспечивая вам головную боль с конфликтами версий.

Comment: по правде говоря я просто хотел скачать их все для оффлайн артефактов :)

Comment: Ну, обычно все репозитории Maven вполне можно выкачать через wget (гуглим `wget recursive download`) и установить в локальный репозиторий (гуглим `maven install 3rd party jar`). У вас в вопросе классическая [проблема XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/5577). Если бы вы подробнее описали _зачем_ вам это нужно, вам бы предложили более релевантное решение.

Comment: @for1ton, спасибо. не знал про проблему XY :)